What is the Big O Notation of f(x) = (n 2)
I am confused about the complexity of this function:
       ⎧⎫
() = ⎩2⎭ 

I read it is Θ(²).
The explanation given is that there is a formula (−1)/2 which was used to turn () into Θ(²). What is that formula?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

"there is a formula (−1)/2 ... What is that formula?": didn't you just provide the formula? Can you rephrase your question?

I suppose your question is how that formula is derived.
The vertical notation represents a binomial coefficient. It can also be written as:
2
It represents the number of ways you can choose two items from a set of  items. For instance, if you have items ,  and , then you can choose either  and , or  and , or  and . So 32 is 3.
This is similar to the number of ways you can select a row and a column from an × matrix, but where the column number should be greater than the row number to avoid duplicates. Like this for =5:
. X X X X
. . X X X
. . . X X
. . . . X
. . . . .

The number of X in the above visualisation is thus also 2 and it is clearly half of the number of X in this one:
. X X X X
X . X X X
X X . X X
X X X . X
X X X X .

So it is half of the number of matrix cells minus the size of the diagonal, i.e. it is (²−)/2, which is (−1)/2.
This is also known as a triangular number, namely −1.
In asymptotic complexity, we can say Θ((²−)/2) is Θ(²) because only the term with the greatest power is significant, and its positive coefficient is not significant for asymptotic behaviour.

(n k) written vertically refers to the combination n choose k. It's the number of ways you can select k items from a group of n where the order in which you picked them does not matter. The formula for this in general is n! / (k! * (n - k)!).
If you substitute in 2 for k, You get n! / (2! * (n - 2)!) which simplifies to n * (n-1) / 2, which is O(n^2).

The given function f(x) = (n 2) represents the number of ways to choose 2 elements out of n elements, which is also known as the combination formula (n k).
(n 2) = n(n-1)/2 = (n^2-n)/2
Dominant term is: n^2/2 so overall time complexity is theta (n^2)
​
